# Android infinite/ circular horizontal scrolling layout?

Tags: java, android, layout, infinite

I just got the ADW EX Launcher and found that it has an "Infinite Scrolling" feature. I opened up hierarchy viewer in the Android SDK and found that it is using the Workspace and Draglayer layout. I got a demo working of the Workspace.java from the 2011 Google I/O app, and it works great.

Now my question: how can I have that workspace scroll infinitely/ circular, so when you get to the last "screen" you scroll back to the first? Whether or not DragLayer is used for this purpose, how can I achieve the same effect in a standard application (not launcher)?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have any idea how this functionality is working in Launcher application ?